# Meaning of the word 'figure' in "The figures involved are truly very large."?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> The figures involved are truly very large.

I read it from the [Collins Dictionary definition of "large"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/large)

Meaning 2:

> A large amount or number of people or things is more than the average amount or number.

Example

> The figures involved are truly very large.

**Does it mean...**
Single figure: 0-9, Double figures: 10-19, Three figures: 20-29
...
**this one?**

Comment: It means **the numbers**.

Comment: 'Double figures' is 10-99, 'three figures' is 100-999 - but the example just means that very many people or things, or very large sums of money, are involved.

Comment: First definition: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/figure

Answer (score 3):

It is a very poor example.

When they say in the definition “more than the average amount or number,” that really cannot apply to numbers themselves because there is no “average” number.

When people say things like that, they are referencing **IMPLICITLY** a typical range of numbers. The statement is meaningless without reference to that typical range.
Even if the typical range is understood, it is a vague statement because “very large” is subjective.

A more numerate person might say

> The numbers are multiples of what are typical

or

> The numbers are orders of magnitude larger than are typical.

Comment: I agree it's a terrible example sentence because it doesn't illustrate the usage  well. It's a fine sentence in context though. We know it's talking about "more than average" because that's the definition it is part of. If we saw it in a paragraph talking about whatever was being measured, the meaning would likely be apparent.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the context of a word matter. Though I am not a native speaker. Is it possible that native speakers in UK have different sayings from US for numerate expressions?

Comment: By the way, I think this dictionary is still decent in many other aspects. I often use both this dictionoary an oxford dictionary interchangeably.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree that in a specific context the average implicitly referred to would probably be quite apparent, but there is no context in a dictionary. Hence the OP’s confusion. But even in a context where the referenced average is clear, “very large” is much vaguer than a comparison among numbers needs to be. That is the whole point about numbers: comparisons can be made with great precision.

Comment: @JeffMorrow There are so many ways this could be a better example, so my comment was just a quibble about context. That the example is attached to the quoted definition that says "more than the average amount or number" provides the missing context.  I think if this was a dictionary targeted at EFL students, like https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/large the examples would be much better.

Comment: @StatsCruncher I am not equipped to talk about informal English outside the US. But I do assist at an English-language math help site that has mathematically trained helpers from North America, the UK, Australia, and India. We never seem to express ourselves in ways that are not mutually understandable (not that the students always get what is said). Based on that, I’d say that there are few significant regional differences in the technical English for mathematics.

Comment: @ColleenV Do you think I need to edit? I get that you are saying the dictionary does provide context by identifying the referent as average number. Part of my problem is that “average number” is absurd on its own; it in turn requires context because numbers in general have no average. I am happy to edit if you think it advisable.

Comment: I don't think you need to edit just for me - I'm more literal-minded than a lot of people, so sometimes the quibbles I have with things are completely invisible to normal people. (i.e. "people with a typical amount of literal-mindedness when compared to the pool of people that participate in online forums" :))

Comment: @Jeff Morrow Wow, your experience is quite informative. Fantastic.